# Order by Nulls alphabetically then Not Nulls

Tags: sql-server, case, sql-order-by, union

I have a dataset where I'm trying to sort by having null startdate values first, then by lastname.  Then nonnull startdates, also by last name:

```
  declare @t table
  (lastname varchar(100),
  firstname varchar(50),
  startdate date)

  insert into @t
  values('Smith', 'John', '01/01/2023'),
  ('Marshall', 'Tom', NULL),
  ('Thomas', 'Frank', '01/01/2022'),
  ('Schmidt', 'Mike', NULL),
  ('Carter', 'Gary', '03/01/2023'),
  ('Belle', 'Albert', NULL)

  LastName     FirstName       StartDate
 Smith         John               2023-01-01
 Marshall      Tom               NULL
 Thomas        Frank             2022-01-01
 Schmidt       Mike              NULL
 Carter        Gary             2023-03-01
 Belle         Albert           NULL
```

Desired Output:

```
  LastName     FirstName        StartDate
   Belle         Albert           NULL
   Marshall       Tom             NULL
   Schmidt        Mike            NULL
   Carter        Gary             2023-03-01
   Smith         John             2023-01-01
   Thomas        Frank            2022-01-01
```

I've tried doing a Union:

```
  select * 
  into #nulls
  from @t
  where startdate is null
  order by lastname

  select * 
  into #nonnulls
  from @t
  where startdate is not null
  order by lastname

  select *
  from #nulls
  UNION
  select *
  from #nonnulls
```

I've also tried using Order by Case:

```
  select *
  from @t
  order by case when startdate is null then lastname 
                when startdate is not null then lastname end
```

Comment: Think about your `CASE`; it effectively is x = then z else z. It *always* resolves to z. You need *different* results for the different results.

Comment: How about `select * from @t order by case when startdate is null then 0 else 1 end, lastname`?

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient version of the `ORDER BY CASE` is to use `UNION ALL` to combine the two halves, and sort it using an ordering column

```sql
SELECT *, 1 AS ordering
FROM @t
WHERE startdate IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT *, 2
FROM @t
WHERE startdate IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY
  ordering,
  lastname
```

This allows the server to use a [*Merge Concatenation*](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/t-sql-queries/avoiding-sorts-merge-join-concatenation) rather than a *Sort*.